# Multithreading determinant computation of a Big Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix

I've been trying to design an algorithm for computing determinant of Big square Matrices (N <= 1000). I am allowed to use multithreading, but still, I can't design the algorithm. The assignment states, that I should use Gaussian elimination method. Yet, there are no input data, so the testing data is on me. For big matrices (N ~1000) it's a binary matrix, otherwise - matrix of integers. I wonder, if there exists a relatively time efficient ( less than 10 seconds ) multithread algorithm for this task. Would be glad to hear opinions.

EDIT:: I came up with idea of using partial pivoting to find a row with maximum at current iterating position, swapping it with current row (such heuristic keeps precision the best). And then, the parallel part, is to do row adding in multithread ( I used 8 threads, since it gave the best results on quad-core) if the matrix is big enough. 
Such method gave more precise results, and efficiency raised with matrix size relatively to one thread method.
It actually turned out to be quite easy to implement.

Comment: Do you have to implement it yourself (assignment) or you're looking for something already implemented? You can use Gaussian elimination to compute it (if you have to use it): have a look on Wikipedia.

Comment: What have you done already? If you forget for a moment that the code should be multithreaded, how do you intend to compute the determinant?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth
The solution for smaller matrices (N <= 300) is trivial Gauss elimination and multiplying diagonal.
Now I'm figuring out how to deal with bigger ones.
I'm thinking of breaking up matrix into 4 parts (since when n=250 it works fast enough), eliminate and the multiply diagonal. The problem is, that each part would have to wait until the previous is done, so multithreading becomes useless. 
I also thought to first break initial matrix into blocks, do the computation simultaneously, and then compute determinant. I have no idea how to break it though.

Comment: Thinking of it now, it's more complex. I would have to add the first row to every other, same with the second and so on. So breaking up into 4 parts won't  do the job.

Comment: That's correct. I doubt that computing the determinant in less than $O(n^3)$ for a dense $n\times n$ matrix is feasible in practice (in the same sense as matrix-matrix multiplication is $O(n^3)$, the Strassen and Winogradov algorithms notwithstanding). There is also likely not a lot of parallelism available.

Comment: That said, you can do multifrontal methods for the Gaussian elimination steps, which can run in parallel. Of course, this is an absolutely non-trivial enterprise on which you're likely going to spend months and thousands of lines of code.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth
Thanks for response. That is quite odd, since I have chosen this task from one of many as assignment for semestral project, so I was assuming that a relatively easy way should be present.

Comment: No, not at all. Computing determinants is *difficult* for large matrices!

Comment: @LevKolomazov Then you should probably discuss this with the person that assigned the task -- maybe they had something specific in mind that you (and we) aren't realizing? Maybe they just wanted you to implement the standard Gaussian elimination and don't care about peak performance or multithreading (*allowed* does not mean *required*!) or very large matrices? (As an instructor, I much prefer students asking for clarification right away to them spending months grinding down a rabbit hole due to a misunderstanding...)

Comment: Agreed on that.

I came up with the idea though. When we do Gauss elemination, the row-to-row computation is independent. Say, we are given matrix $\begin{bmatrix} a - 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\b - 6 & 5 & 8 & 9\\c -  10 & 12 & 13 & 14 \\d -  20 & 19 & 81 & 96 \end{bmatrix}$ 
Than adding a+b, a+c, a+d can all run in parallel, after that we do b + c, c + d also in parallel and so on. 
Hope I'll be able to programm that in 3 days till deadline. Please, comment if you consider this way improper.